# Modelling single-pole, double-throw switch in PSpice

Tags: switches, simulation, pspice, spdt

What is the easiest way to model an ideal single-pole, double-throw switch in PSpice? And a single-pole, triple-throw switch?

Comment: As well as a single pole triple throw switch

Comment: not sure, but maybe it could be done with a "text" label, that's how they make a "transformer" using 2 inductors.

Comment: See [this page](https://www.pspice.com/passive/switches). No idea why you couldn't find it with google, though. Note the **Sw_tOpen** and **Sw_tClose**, which allow you to set the time you want for activating the switch (opening or closing.) I'm pretty sure these are only good for .TRAN. I would suspect for other run types they'd retain their initial condition.

Comment: Refer to the PSpice Reference Guide, Voltage-Controlled Switch. Use Capture parts S or S_ST.